# How I set notification light without blink in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I used this for notification but i want to disable the blink of  notification light. How I do this please advice me

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
builder.setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
builder.setLights(0xff00ff00, 1000 * 60 * 60, 1); // on for one hour, off for 1ms
```

Comment: Is there no way to stop blink totally?

Comment: for one hour i think it should 1000*60*60 not 1000*60*60*60 right?